# Maven Build Number Plugin version not filtered

Tags: git, maven

I'd like to filter my buildNumber (git revision number), provided by the [buildnumber-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/buildnumber-maven-plugi) in a property file, so I can access it from my software.

I got the following pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>xxxx</groupId>
        <artifactId>xxxx</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>..</relativePath>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>xxxx</artifactId>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources/</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>create</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <shortRevisionLength>5</shortRevisionLength>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

and the folloling file src/main/resources/revision.properties:

```
branch = ${scmBranch}
revision = ${buildNumber}
version = ${project.version}
```

After I ran mvn clean install, which produces the following output:

```
...
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ xxx ---
[INFO] Deleting D:\parsp\git\acm-utils\target
[INFO]
[INFO] --- buildnumber-maven-plugin:1.3:create (default) @ xxx ---
[INFO] ShortRevision tag detected. The value is '5'.
[INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "git rev-parse --verify --short=5 HEAD"
[INFO] Working directory: D:\parsp\git\acm-utils
[INFO] Storing buildNumber: 70cd7 at timestamp: 1423479895763
[INFO] Storing buildScmBranch: master
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ xxx ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO]
...
```

I get the following resultinf file in target/classes, where only the maven version is filtered into that file:

```
branch = ${scmBranch}
revision = ${buildNumber}
version = 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
```

Is there anything I missed?

Comment: Because they are provided by [buildnumber-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/buildnumber-maven-plugin/create-mojo.html).

Comment: BTW: Why have you changed the phase for buildnumber-maven-plugin and didn't kept the defaults? Remove the `<phase>...</phase>` tag for buildnumber-maven-plugin.

Comment: @khmarbaise The buildnumber-maven-plugin is exactly the plugin I used (see pom sniplets in the question). The sniplet was copied from here: http://mojo.codehaus.org/buildnumber-maven-plugin/usage.html and that includes the phase tag. But you are right, it is not neccessary but it should not break the functionality since is before the `process-resources` phase, where the resources are filtered.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a work around, than an answer, but I figured that 
a `validate` followed by `install` works for me. But that's of course no practical way to use it...

Did you find any solutions by yourself in the meantime?